# Editar contenido de una fila con div

Tags: jquery

```
 <div id="row"> 
   <div id="id"> 1 </div>
   <div id="nombre"> Henry maldonado </div>
   <div id="cedula"> 11223366 </div>
   <div id="cargo"> Vendedor</div>
   <div id="editar"> <button>Editar</button></div>
   <div id="eliminar"> <button>Eliminar</button></div>
  </div>

  <div id="row"> 
    <div id="id"> 2 </div>
    <div id="nombre"> Jose maldonado </div>
    <div id="cedula"> 12362514</div>
    <div id="cargo"> Cajero </div>
    <div id="editar"> <button>Editar</button></div>
    <div id="eliminar"> <button>Eliminar</button></div>
  </div>
```

La informacion se llena al traer de la base de datos
Quiero que al darle editar y la informacion que ponga en uno input actualice los datos del de la fila que selecciones.
Asi pongo los valores a los input que necesito editar

$('.contenido').on('click','.editar',function() {

```
`introducir el código aquí`fila = $(this).closest('div')
  var id = $(this).parent().find('div').eq(0).text();
  var nomre= $(this).parent().find('div').eq(1).text();
  var cedula = $(this).parent().find('div').eq(2).text();
  var cargo = $(this).parent().find('div').eq(3).text();
  $("#idtxt").val(id);
  $("#nametxt").val(nomre);
  console.log(id);
  console.log(nombre);
  console.log(fila)
```

/*

});

ahora necesito al darle actualizar a un boton me actualice sola la fila y solo me actualice los div id, nombre,cedula, y cargo.

Comment: yo creo que en tu código le falta información, principalmente como tienes los inputs

Comment: Claro ahi falta los otros input y los valores para esos input la tomo de la fila del div pero lo que necesito es volver a poner la informacion editadas de los input en la fila del div que la tome. Espero y me entienda.